# How to put div behind div in grid and offset it?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that contain poster images. I want to put another poster behind each of those and do the following:

- offset it by some x and y values
- overlay it with semi-transparent div to make it darker
- reduce its size while maintaining aspect ratio

How can this be done within the existing grid and and without changes to the two posters in the front?

[image]

```js
films = [
  {id: 0, title: 'Welcome Home', year: 2009},
  {id: 2, title: 'Aurie', year: 2001},
  {id: 3, title: 'Hardship', year: 2005},
  {id: 4, title: 'Forth to the past', year: 2004}]

data = {
  film0: films[0],
  film1: films[1],
  film2: films[2],
  film3: films[3]
}

function update() {
  poster1 = "https://unsplash.it/458/679.jpg";
  poster2 = "https://unsplash.it/458/679.jpg";
  document.getElementById("name1").innerText = data.film1.title;
  document.getElementById("name2").innerText = data.film2.title;
  document.getElementById("year1").innerText = data.film1.year;
  document.getElementById("year2").innerText = data.film2.year;
  document.getElementById("poster1").setAttribute("src", poster1);
  document.getElementById("poster2").setAttribute("src", poster2);
}

update();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 25% 8% 25% 20%;
  grid-gap: 0.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.header,
.footer {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 50%;
}

.poster-container {
  position: relative;
}

.poster {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 7%;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 110%;
}

.year {
  font-size: 90%;
}

.poster-container:hover > .title {}

a {
    all: unset;
}

a:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.shutdown{
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 1%;
}

.shutdown:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="header"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="poster-container">
        <img class="poster" id="poster1" />
        <div class="title">
          <a id="poster1-link" target="_blank">
            <div class="name" id="name1"></div>
          </a>
          <div class="year" id="year1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="poster-container">
        <img class="poster" id="poster2" />
        <div class="title">
          <a id="poster2-link" target="_blank">
            <div class="name" id="name2"></div>
          </a>
          <div class="year" id="year2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you investigated using pseudo elements?

Comment: I just looked into it but I did not get how this might help. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Can you alter the HTML? May just make it a bit easier if you can, but probably not essential.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. As long as the JS part still works and appearance of the front posters (including their text overlay) does not change

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution:

```js
films = [
  {id: 0, title: 'Welcome Home', year: 2009},
  {id: 2, title: 'Aurie', year: 2001},
  {id: 3, title: 'Hardship', year: 2005},
  {id: 4, title: 'Forth to the past', year: 2004}]

data = {
  film0: films[0],
  film1: films[1],
  film2: films[2],
  film3: films[3]
}

function update() {
  poster0 = "https://unsplash.it/458/679.jpg";
  poster1 = "https://unsplash.it/458/679.jpg";
  poster2 = "https://unsplash.it/458/679.jpg";
  document.getElementById("name1").innerText = data.film1.title;
  document.getElementById("name2").innerText = data.film2.title;
  document.getElementById("year1").innerText = data.film1.year;
  document.getElementById("year2").innerText = data.film2.year;
  document.getElementById("poster1").setAttribute("src", poster1);
  document.getElementById("poster2").setAttribute("src", poster2);
  document.getElementById("poster0").setAttribute("src", poster0);
  document.getElementById("poster3").setAttribute("src", poster0);
}

update();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 25% 8% 25% 20%;
  grid-gap: 0.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.header,
.footer {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 50%;
}

.poster-container {
  position: relative;
}

.poster {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 7%;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 110%;
}

.year {
  font-size: 90%;
}

.remove {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 90%;
}

a {
  all: unset;
}

a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shutdown {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 1%;
}

.shutdown:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

;

.poster0 {}

.double0 {
  position: relative;
}

.double3 {
  position: relative;
}

.poster0 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: -10%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.poster3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50%;
  top: -10%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.overlay0 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: -10%;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.overlay3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50%;
  top: -10%;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="double0">
        <div class="overlay0"></div>
        <img class="poster poster0" id="poster0" />
        <div class="poster-container">
          <img class="poster" id="poster1" />
          <div class="title">
            <a id="poster1-link" target="_blank">
              <div class="name" id="name1"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="year" id="year1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div></div>

      <div class="double3">
        <div class="overlay3"></div>
        <img class="poster poster3" id="poster3" />
        <div class="poster-container">
          <img class="poster" id="poster2" />
          <div class="title">
            <a id="poster2-link" target="_blank">
              <div class="name" id="name2"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="year" id="year2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).